# Decision Trees - Taking a long time to process String values but working fine for float values. How to understand?

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am trying to build a decision tree classifier using the code below

`from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()`

and my data is 

`age type_income loan_purpose loan_amount offer
18  Student study   500 yes
18  Student study   600 yes
18  Student study   700 yes
18  Student study   800 yes
. . .`

so the decision tree gives out an error saying that it can't convert Student into a float value.

What can I do to resolve this?
I don't want the data to be converted manually to float through preprocessing I want that the algorithm itself handles this issue. Is there any parameter to be passed which can fix this automatically?

Answer (score 3):

`sklearn` expects all inputs to be continuous, which is why there is no modules to automatically convert categorical variables to floats. You will have to do some kind of preprocessing manually.

However, there is a rather convenient option: go for onehot encoding of your categorical data (assuming there are not too many different levels for those factorsm in your example `type_income` and `loan_purpose`). Just converting the strings to floats (eg `Student`-> `0`, `Employee`->`1`) is not adviseable because then `sklearn` will assume that there is a relation `Student < Employee`.

I suggest you take a look at section 4.3.5 of [this documentation page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html)

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done manually or handled by the decision tree algorithm by passing some parameters.

*Note*: The biggest work of machine learning or other related fields is not the actual algorithm - it is the data collection and preprocessing. Hence, you really cant get away with those things or expect functions to handle them on their own.

You need to convert String to a corresponding digit (like a mapping) for which one-hot encoding can be used. There is no way for the above function call to `DecisionTree` to do that for you, however, there are preprocessing functions that help you achieve the same.

(The reason for that is that a lot of computations in the background are calculation and identifier intensive. Strings use up additional memory slowing down the computation - it is much faster hence, to use integers.)

You can also write your own if it is important. Check out [One-hot encoding function from sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

***Some additional information***

Another way to make the one-hot encoding and your algorithm efficient is to use [sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) matrices. As datasets can be intensive and huge, sparse matricies just kind of "zip" your one-hot encoded array so that it can be stored efficiently in memory.